# Referee stopped match mid-game and lost control, what happens?

Tags: football

On the weekend the ref was blatantly giving all the decisions to the home team, and so was receiving some grief from the sidelines. In the 52nd minute one of the away players said to the home player 'How much are you paying him?' The referee went ahead and gave him a red card. After a few minutes there was a disagreement between the linesman (away team parent) and the ref, and the linesman walked off and refused to linesman the game. The ref declared the game abandoned and blew for the final whistle in the 52nd minute. The score was 2-2, and bearing in mind this was a junior game, who wins?

Answer (score 5):

Nobody wins, the match has been abandoned. While in theory [Law 7.5 states](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-duration-of-the-match_2018/chapters/abandoned-match-2018) :

> An abandoned match is replayed unless the competition rules or organisers determine otherwise.

You can bet your bottom dollar that the organisers *will* be getting involved.